# `MapnikRasterizer` is giving an error (bad allocation) in FME

Tags: tiles, cad, fme-form

What could be the issue here. `MapnikRasterizer` is giving an error!

```
 MapnikRasterizer(MapnikFactory): Performing rasterization...

 MapnikRasterizer(MapnikFactory): Failed to rasterize data. The error was: bad allocation

 MapnikRasterizer(MapnikFactory): A fatal error has occurred. Check the logfile above for details
```

Here is the [FME file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwMirpbclFbrLUF6d1M4RXNhZVE/view?usp=sharing)

A snapshot:
[image]

As stated here in this [article](https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/20873/bad-allocation-error-using-mapnikrasterizer.html), there is a bug with `MapnikRasterizer`. this transformer unlike `ImageRasterizer` gives the option to change color of line, text, polygon etc. If using `MapnikRasterizer` is not possible how can I customize the color of the lines and the text before `ImageRasterizer`ing.

Answer (score -1):

The data volumes seem low but I'm wondering what the size of the actual image is that you're going to output? That may be the problem.  Can you try with a lower resolution and see if that helps. You may need to tile the data prior to going into the rasterizer if you're looking to produce a huge huge output raster.

Comment: I used `ImageRasterizer` and it was fine. however it does not offer the customization that `MapnikRasterizer` offers. how can I customise polygon fill color, line color and text color prior to using `ImageRasterizer`. what transformer should I use?